# How to add every other n nonblank cells in a column in Excel/Google Spreadsheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

So I have a column that may have empty cells, but I only want to sum every 7 cells that have numbers. I have looked into SUMIF but it seems like that won't do what I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have your numbers in B2:B, to sum every 7th row

```
=sum(filter(B2:B, mod(row(B2:B),7)=2))
```

[Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13sW-ed-lf2-IZJOf1usSIsiiBAvJw1gmUmm-rRzai7A/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be adding filter to your column and filter only showing the non-blank cells.  then add another column that has the sums of every seven cells.